# Alias not associated with private key in PhoneGap build

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I have a problem with PhoneGap Build hopefully someone can help me.
In short:

1. keytool tells us we have a valid keystore-file, confirming our
   password and alias is correct.
2. we upload the keystore to phonegap build, associated with the confirmed right alias.
3. we unlock this key and build the app using it.
4. build fails with error: "Error - Alias not associated with private key "

This seems to be a rather persistent issue, any updates/solutions? This topic as well as this one (http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/...) seem to end with the same dramatic solution: 'release it under a new app'. Releasing under a new app is simply impossible because this is a B2B app and we want to update our app.

We are able to manually build the app.